# Multiple definition compile errors using -pg flag for gprof in C++

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, gprof

I am trying to compile some C++ code to be used with gprof, and have tried using the -pg flag, but am getting errors regarding multiple definitions for each of my functions.  My command is basically g++ -o -pg my_exec my_code.cp -mylib.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you show contents of my_code.cp ?

Comment: I think I figured out my problem.  -o and -pg appear to be mutually exclusive and conflict with each other.  Removing the -o and the executable name, results in everything compiling fine, and being executable from ./a.out